# In what Deep Space Nine episode did Bashir dump an armload of PADDs on Sisko's desk?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, episode-identification

As the title says, I'm looking for a Deep Space Nine episode where Bashir dumps an armload of PADDs on Sisko's desk.  I want to take a screenshot of the scene so I can humorously demonstrate how the show was a product of its time--specifically, how no one predicted ubiquitous wireless information access.

(To be fair, I watched the show all the way through a couple of years ago, and this is one of only a very few things that seem dated now.)

I thought I remembered that the episode in question was "Statistical Probabilities" from season 6, where Bashir presents Sisko with he and his friends' analysis of the Dominion War and recommends surrender.  Reviewing the episode, however, I see that while a number of PADDs are involved in that scene, Bashir calmly hands them over one at a time.  The scene where he dumps a number of them on Sisko's desk is apparently from some other episode, if I didn't hallucinate it entirely.

Comment: https://plus.google.com/+FabianScherschel/posts/QWit554e4PH

Comment: Or maybe multiple PADDs [didn't go far enough](http://www.bitrebels.com/geek/a-card-deck-made-with-52-iphones/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, according to [this trail](https://plus.google.com/+FabianScherschel/posts/QWit554e4PH) on the Google+ of [**this guy**](https://plus.google.com/+FabianScherschel), it is indeed "Statistical Probabilities".

Quoting:

> **Fabian Scherschel** Apparently PADDs don't do multitasking. Bashir just handed about eight of them to Sisko.

Then at the bottom:

> **Thomas Bourque** Was the part about Bashir handing the PADDs to Sisko from "Statistical Probabilities"? That is one of my favorite DS9 episodes. :D
>
> **Fabian Scherschel**
> Yes. Watched that last night. Great episode.

Not the best source, but no reason to think this it isn't correct.

This then enabled @TZHX to go fetch a screen cap, confirming the accuracy.

[image: Sisko with pads handed to him one-by-one by Bashir]

Also, from [here](http://www.avclub.com/tvclub/star-trek-deep-space-nine-statistical-probabilitie-103945):

> - The sight of Bashir brandishing multiple PADDs cracked me up.

[image]

Comment: @TZHX appears to have gotten the capture from [here](http://de.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Statistische_Wahrscheinlichkeiten), which is the German Memory Alpha page for this episode.

Comment: Or... I screen-capped it from skipping through the episode to find the correct place. Take your pick. :)

Comment: @TZHX:   OK, then +1 for Google image search!   And then it means TZHX is confirming this is from that episode.

Comment: ”Jake said he’ll stop buying me Kindles when I read his damn novel.“

Comment: @Praxis: 《wink》

Comment: I think we can safely assume and hope this is the first and last time anyone references Google+ in an answer.

Comment: It was an image of Bashir brandishing the PADDs I was looking for, not Sisko.  But apparently I misremembered.

Comment: @Sean, the quote says it happened.  Someone should be able to get the cap you seek.

Comment: @Sean, ask and ye shall receive.